Jetpack compose - Handling deep links with multiple NavHosts
How to properly handle deep links with multiple NavHosts?
In my app, I have two NavHosts. The first one is the root, and the second is for the HomeScreen. Deep links work correctly when I add them to a screen in the root NavHost. However, they don’t work when I add them to a screen contained within the HomeScreen NavHost. The reason I have two NavHosts, of course, is because of the Bottom bar on the HomeScreen. It’s worth noting that both screens that should handle the deep links have the same basePath, but the Route models are different. Below, I’ve included sample code illustrating the problem.
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    @ExperimentalAnimationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen().apply {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                mainViewModel.state.isLoading
            }
        }

        enableEdgeToEdge()

        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    if (mainViewModel.state.startDestination != null) {
                        RootNavGraph(
                            navController = navController,
                            startDestination = mainViewModel.state.startDestination!!
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: Any
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        authNavGraph(navController = navController)
        composable<MainRoute> {
            HomeScreen(rootNavController = navController)
        }
        composable<ScreenXRoute>(
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink<ScreenXRoute>(
                    basePath = "${BuildConfig.BASE_URL}something"
                )
            )
        ) {
            ScreenX(onNavigateUp = navController::navigateUp)
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class ScreenXRoute(val id: Long)

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    rootNavController: NavHostController,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    HomeScreenUi(
        currentDestination = currentDestination,
        onNavigate = { route ->
            navController.navigate(route) {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                    saveState = true
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
        }) { paddingValues ->
        MainNavGraph(
            navController = navController,
            rootNavController = rootNavController,
            homeScreenBottomPadding = paddingValues
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    rootNavController: NavHostController,
    homeScreenBottomPadding: PaddingValues
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = VeryCoolGraph
    ) {
        profileNavGraph(navController = navController, homeScreenBottomPadding = homeScreenBottomPadding)
        veryCoolGraph(rootNavHostController = rootNavController, navController = navController, homeScreenBottomPadding = homeScreenBottomPadding)
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.veryCoolGraph(
    rootNavHostController: NavHostController,
    navController: NavHostController,
    homeScreenBottomPadding: PaddingValues
) {
    navigation<VeryCoolGraph>(
        startDestination = Screen1Route()
    ) {
        composable<Screen1Route>(
            enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
            exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink<Screen1Route>(
                    basePath = "${BuildConfig.BASE_URL}something"
                )
            )) {
            val screen1ViewModel = it.sharedViewModel<SharedViewModel>(navController = navController)

            Screen1(
                viewModel = screen1ViewModel,
                homeScreenBottomPadding = homeScreenBottomPadding
            )
        }
        composable<Screen2Route> {
            val viewModel =
                it.sharedViewModel<SharedViewModel>(navController = navController)

            Screen2(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                onNavigateUp = navController::navigateUp
            )
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class Screen1Route(
    val page: Int? = null,
    val additionalInformation: String? = null,
    val price: String? = null
)

